# SVN Branch Spec , How do I

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Say I have few folders in trunk

1. trunk/documentation
2. trunk/ApplicationServices
3. trunk/Release
4. trunk/ApplicationUI

I want to Branch out *ApplicationServices* and *ApplicationUI* to a new branch.

I want to create a **branch spec**

- ../trunk/ApplicationServices   ../branches/**BAU01**/ApplictionServices
- ../trunk/ApplictionUI      ../branches/**BAU01**/ApplictionUI

**Not to take in the Rlease and Documentation folders i want to leave them in the trunk and not want to version them or branch them.**

and then create a branch based on the specification. This is how i used to do it previous Sourcecontrol mechanisam,

how can i do this in SVN, Tortoise options dont show anything which resembles a branch spec.

can you please help.

Thanks.

Vinay

Comment: If you copy those projects from trunk to branches/BAU01, you already have a branch to work from. Will this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
svn copy svn://server/repos/trunk/trunk/ApplicationServices 
                       svn://server/repos/branches/BAU01/ApplictionServices
svn copy svn://server/repos/trunk/trunk/ApplictionUI 
                       svn://server/repos/branches/BAU01/ApplictionUI
```

This will create a branch of those two projects, and keep them together in the branches/BAU01 locaiton.

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSvn you can use the [Branch/Tag](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-branch-1) feature. There is a fairly to-the-point tutorial about it [here](http://www.igorexchange.com/node/87#branches).

Answer (score 0):

The short story is: Use "copy to" and give the branch name as the destination.

In SVN, a branch is just a directory. There are a variety of ways to create a directory, and then copy the existing files there.